# Python Searches a character expression for a string that is specified as a word, similar to SAS INDEXW function

Tags: python, pandas, sas, data-manipulation

I tried to mimic the similar task of `SAS` function `INDEXW()` in Python. [INDEXW](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p0korze1qnq4len1mvlb5o98ht1n.htm)

```
# Sample
Col1                  Col2
FIG AVE               FIG AVE
LAKE HATCHINEHA RD    HATCHINEHA RD
MERLE CIR             MERLE CIR
ARCH ST               W ARCH ST
WESTVIEW DR           CLAYMORE CT
```

```
def INDEXW(source, excerpt):
    delimiters = " "
    regexPattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, delimiters))
    return any([str(excerpt).strip() == word for word in [x.strip() for x in re.split(regexPattern, str(source))]])


Sample["RESULT1"] = Sample[["Col1","Col2"]].apply(lambda x: INDEXW(*x), axis=1)
Sample["RESULT2"] = Sample[["Col2","Col1"]].apply(lambda x: INDEXW(*x), axis=1)
```

The above returns all `False`, which are incorrect.

```
# Answer
Col1                  Col2             RESULT1    RESULT2
FIG AVE               FIG AVE          True       True
LAKE HATCHINEHA RD    HATCHINEHA RD    False      True
MERLE CIR             MERLE CIR        True       True
ARCH ST               W ARCH ST        True       False
WESTVIEW DR           CLAYMORE CT      False      False
```

I know that we can use `find()` to get the result correctly. (`find()` works well)

Just curious how should I modify `INDEXW()` to get the result? Thanks

Comment: It is not clear to me which characters is being searched in the columns? Is it the starting positions of `Col2` in `Col1`?

Comment: `indexw` searches one string for another string, but with the requirement that it be fully between delimiters - think `index word`.  So, `indexw('CAR','CARPARK')` would return `false`, but `indexw('CAR', 'CAR PARK')` would return `true`.

Comment: Peter - the issue I suspect is that your 'search for' word is not *one word*, but is several words.  Then when you split it by the delimiter, you end up with only looking at one word at a time.

Comment: @Joe Yeah, your right. That is my issue. How to match that. `find()` works well but I just want to think is it possible to modify my `INDEXW()` function to get the same result?

Comment: I think it will be more complicated if the 'to find' is allowed to have multiple words - at that point you need to not try and split up the original string, and instead search for " word " (with delimiters on either end) or permit "word " and " word" at start/end...

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue:

```
def INDEXW(source, excerpt):
    from itertools import permutations, combinations
    delimiters = " "
    regexPattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, delimiters))
    features = [x.strip() for x in re.split(regexPattern, str(source))]
    tmp = []
    for i in range(len(features)):
        oc = combinations(features, i + 1)
        for c in oc:
            tmp.append(list(c))
    return any([str(excerpt).strip() == word for word in [' '.join(x) for x in tmp]])
```

```
# TEST
INDEXW("LAKE HATCHINEHA RD", "HATCHINEHA RD")
> True

INDEXW("ARCH ST", "W ARCH ST")
> False

INDEXW("W ARCH ST", "ARCH ST")
> True
```

Comment: Is there possible to optimize and speed up? When applying on dataframe with `df[["Col1","Col2"]].apply(lambda x: INDEXW(*x), axis=1)`, really slow.